# A dubious sequence

Tags: number-sequence, sequence, word-sequence

I created this puzzle. Observe the following sequence carefully.
$$\text{men, xomt, asem, nub, chesbet, teht, hat}$$
Now answer this question:

Why did I run around crazy after this? What's my problem?

Bonus:
Find out how the sequence above is related to the following one.
$$4-13-1-78, 210-34-69-82, -4-9010-84-82-85-77, 76-10-68, -2-646-3-784, 80716, -11-88-86-69-82$$
Hint 1:

> How do you know this question? (-e) + The Mentalist

Hint 2:

> >>>

Hint 3: (for Bonus question):

> What does this world want besides law?

Answer (score 6):

**Partial Answer**

From Googling about a bit it seems like all the words are

> Names for Egyptian alchemy symbols

In particular, the correspondence seems to be

> Men = Iron
>  Xomt = Copper
>  Asem = Electrum
>  Nub = Gold
>  Chesbet = Enamel or Sapphire
>  Teht = Lead
>  Hat = Silver

Why did I run around crazy for after this? What's my problem?

> Not sure but if we take Enamel as the Chesbet then the first letters spell out **ICE GELS** so maybe you need some pain relief.

No idea on the Bonus but maybe somebody else will get inspiration.

Comment: Great @hexomino. Try to solve the bonus one. Well done, again. And try to explain how my hints relate to your answer.